# memory leak with quadpy.quad (numerical integration) and TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to perform numerical integration using TensorFlow. And do it many many times in a loop. My RAM memory slowly but steadily increases. The code below reproduces the problem. (Tensorflow 2.3.0)

```
import quadpy
import numpy as np

import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=FutureWarning)
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
    tf.disable_v2_behavior()

import tracemalloc
from pympler import muppy, summary
import pandas as pd


def f(arg):
    return np.multiply.outer(np.random.standard_normal([101, 101, 10]).astype(np.float64), np.sin(arg))


integr = tf.py_function(func=lambda z: quadpy.quad(f, 0.001, 0.999)[0],
                        inp=[0.999], 
                        Tout=tf.float64 )


if __name__=="__main__":    
    top = 5
    trace = 1

    tracemalloc.start(25)
    start = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    prev = start    

    i = 0
    while True:
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(integr)
        i += 1   
    
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("======================================")
            current = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
            stats = current.compare_to(start, 'filename')
            prev_stats = current.compare_to(prev, 'lineno')

            print('Top Diffs since Start')
            for i, stat in enumerate(stats[:top], 1):
                print('top_diffs: ', 'i: ', i, ' stat: ', stat)

            print()
            print('Top Incremental')
            for i, stat in enumerate(prev_stats[:top], 1):
                print('top_incremental: ', 'i: ', i, ' stat: ', stat)

            print()
            print('Top Current')
            for i, stat in enumerate(current.statistics('filename')[:top], 1):
                print('top_current: ', 'i: ', i, ' stat: ', stat)

            print()
            traces = current.statistics('traceback')
            for stat in traces[:trace]:
                print('top_incremental: ', 'memory_blocks: ', stat.count, 'size_kB: ', stat.size / 1024)
                for line in stat.traceback.format():
                    print(line)

            print("======================================")
            all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
            sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
            summary.print_(sum1)                                                     # Prints out a summary of the large objects 
            dataframes = [ao for ao in all_objects if isinstance(ao, pd.DataFrame)]  # Get references to certain types of objects such as dataframe
            for d in dataframes:
                print(d.columns.values)
                print(len(d))
            print("======================================")

            prev = current
```

Discarding pympler and tracemalloc memory consumption I got lines that indicate a memory leak in numpy/core/fromnumeric.py

```
top_diffs:  i:  3  stat:  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:0: size=1595 KiB (+1595 KiB), count=18 (+18), average=88.6 KiB
top_incremental:  i:  4  stat:  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:90: size=1594 KiB (+797 KiB), count=12 (+3), average=133 KiB

top_diffs:  i:  3  stat:  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:0: size=2392 KiB (+2392 KiB), count=21 (+21), average=114 KiB
top_incremental:  i:  5  stat:  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:90: size=2391 KiB (+797 KiB), count=15 (+3), average=159 KiB

top_diffs:  i:  3  stat:  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:0: size=3190 KiB (+3190 KiB), count=26 (+26), average=123 KiB
top_incremental:  i:  4  stat:  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:90: size=3189 KiB (+797 KiB), count=18 (+3), average=177 KiB

top_diffs:  i:  3  stat:  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:0: size=3987 KiB (+3987 KiB), count=28 (+28), average=142 KiB
top_incremental:  i:  4  stat:  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:90: size=3986 KiB (+797 KiB), count=21 (+3), average=190 KiB


top_incremental:  memory_blocks:  3 size_kB:  797.09375
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 90
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2229
    initial=initial, where=where)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/quadpy/c1/_adaptive.py", line 71
    good_values_sum = numpy.sum(value_estimates[..., is_good], axis=-1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/quadpy/_scipy_compat.py", line 49
    max_num_subintervals=limit,
  File "<ipython-input-3-a148c9d4ebcc>", line 47
    integr = tf.py_function(func=lambda z: quadpy.quad(f, 0.001, 0.999)[0],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 302
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 131
    ret = self._func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 242
    return func(device, token, args)
top_incremental:  memory_blocks:  541 size_kB:  47.427734375
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 429
    exec(class_definition, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/quadpy/c1/_gauss_kronrod.py", line 199
    "range_shape",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/quadpy/c1/_adaptive.py", line 45
    range_shape=range_shape,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/quadpy/_scipy_compat.py", line 49
    max_num_subintervals=limit,
  File "<ipython-input-3-a148c9d4ebcc>", line 47
    integr = tf.py_function(func=lambda z: quadpy.quad(f, 0.001, 0.999)[0],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 302
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 131
    ret = self._func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 242
    return func(device, token, args)
```

Thanks You for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this happens because you are using `py_function`, which will [cause the memory to grow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35010) because it keeps track of the gradient.

Instead, you may want to use `numpy_function`.